# OS X - Mount .dmg image into a virtual DVD drive without Toast Titanium

Tags: macos, mount

Toast Titanium 10 offers a way of mounting an image into a virtual DVD drive so that it is viewed as being a separate physical drive by other applications.

I was wondering if there was a way of achieving the same result using the built-in OS X tools (whether GUI or command line), as I am aware it has many of such built in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Toast Titanium 10 offers a way of mounting an image into a virtual DVD
>   drive so that it is viewed as being a separate physical drive by other
>   applications.

**INCORRECT ASSUMPTION.**  When Toast 10 mounts a disk image file, it does so using the same method as Disk Utility.  It does NOT emulate a physical drive, and programs that communicate directly with a physical drive will not recognize the mounted image as a disc.

> I was wondering if there was a way of achieving the same result using
>   the built-in OS X tools

Disk Utility will achieve the "same result" as Toast (which does not create a virtual drive).  An optical drive emulator requires a kernel extension which is not included with OS X.

> there's nothing available for OSX except for Toast that actually
>   mounts the CD or DVD **[image]** like a CD or DVD.

**COMPLETELY WRONG ANSWER.**
There are several applications for Mac which can emulate an optical drive, but Toast is not one of them.
Examples include *"Daemon Tools Lite for Mac"* and *"Virtual CD-RW"*.

Answer (score 1):

The Disk Utility application in the Utilities folder is the GUI front end to the hdid command...  You can perform most of the tasks via the Disk Utility application, and it's easier to use...

Comment: The computer will not recognize the image as a physical DVD drive, despite the image being mounted. (Programs that require mounted DVDs or CDs will not work)

Comment: Actually, I use disk images all the time to replace DVD / CD disks.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally saved the previous.<br>Actually, I use disk images all the time to replace DVD / CD disks.  The issue is that a mounted image can be detected due to the "protocol type".  Device Identifier:        disk5
   Device Node:              /dev/disk5
Content (IOContent):      Apple_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
So if a program wants to, it can check to see if a disk is a disk image.  Sensible for a copy protection scheme, but otherwise, generally unneeded.  disk info <vol> shows this.

Answer (score 0):

[From this URL](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2005050606123892)

> After reading the hdid man (via man hdid) page, I realized that we could mount .DMG images via HTTP under Terminal.app. And even cooler, the segmented images work too. Just reference the http-based DMG via this command: % hdid http://server.company.com/Images/stuff.dmg

Answer (score -2):

Nope there's nothing available for OSX except for Toast that actually mounts the CD or DVD like a CD or DVD.

As you said disk utility in OSX doesn't work for the purpose that 10 million users want it for - to do the same as daemon tools, nero, alcohol can do on PC.

So the options are - buy toast. Install a 500MB program to mount a disc!

The web if full of people asking for the OSX equivalent of Daemon Tools but it will never come.

Comment: `The web if full of people asking for the OSX equivalent of Daemon Tools but it will never come.`   Orly‽ `ovO` *Never*? Why not?